# Excel XML vba write an XML text node to excel worksheet using lastrow

Tags: excel, vba

I Load 200 xml files using a loop and it works.
When I use Debug.Print xmldoc.text, it prints each line 1 time each time for each
xml document using xmldoc.text. That is what I want, but I want it
to load each line in a spreadsheet starting from the last row. Right now it loads
1 line 200 times using the last row. How can I make this work.

```
Sub ReadXMLDoc() 
    Sub LearnAboutNodes() 
        Dim xmldoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument50 
        Dim xmlNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode 
        Dim LastRow as Long
        Set xmldoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument50 
        xmldoc.async = False 

        xmldoc.Load ("C:\yourFile.xml") 
        If xmldoc.hasChildNodes Then 
            Debug.Print "Number of child Nodes: " & xmldoc.childNodes.length 
            For Each xmlNode In xmldoc.childNodes 
                Debug.Print "Node name:" & xmlNode.nodeName 
                Debug.Print "Type:" & xmlNode.nodeTypeString & "(" & xmlNode.nodeType & ")" 
                Debug.Print "Text: " & xmlNode.Text 
                lastrow = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row 
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, lastrow).value = xmldoc.text
            Next xmlNode 
        End If 
        Set xmlDoc = Nothing 
    End Sub 

    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a hanging `End If` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
For Each xmlNode In xmldoc.childNodes 
    'Debug.Print "Node name:" & xmlNode.nodeName 
    'Debug.Print "Type:" & xmlNode.nodeTypeString & "(" & xmlNode.nodeType & ")" 
    'Debug.Print "Text: " & xmlNode.Text       
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lastrow = .Cells(.rows.count,1).End(xlup).Offset(1,0).row 
        .Cells(1, lastrow).value = xmlnode.text
    End With
Next
```